# What is the meaning of "mehr" in this context?

Tags: meaning, german-to-english

The "Assimil - German with Ease" book translated the sentence

> "Die kann allein nicht mehr runter."

as

> She cannot get down on her own.

If the translation is reasonable, what's the meaning of ***mehr*** in this context? I am asking this because I imagine it cannot be simply translated as "more" in this context.

Comment: BTW, though this is certainly a sentence that a native speakers might utter, it is not very idiomatic (and certainly not very polished style). A better version would be "sie schafft es alleine nicht, wieder herunterzukommen" or more colloquially "sie kommt allein nicht mehr runter".

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think the provided translation is leaving it untranslated for no or little good reason. In this context it translates as 'anymore', which changes the meaning slightly:

> She cannot get down on her own anymore.

Answer (score 10):

In this context, "nicht mehr" is a compound that translates to "no more" / "not anymore".

So, it signifies that something was true before, but isn't any longer true. The translation you mentioned seems to omit that aspect.

Comment: Not necessarily. I think that it can mean that she got up there on her own but cannot get back down on her own.

Comment: 'Yes' to Paul's comment. In another way of conveying the same thing, 'she cannot get [back] down again'.  'Again', here, could well translate the 'mehr' in the given context.

Comment: I believe that would be "Die kann allein nicht _wieder_ runter."

Answer (score 0):

Mehr in this context means "longer" (or "more")

So: She cannot get down on her own any longer.  (or anymore)

Better English: She can no longer get down on her own.